# How to Pause an Ansible Playbook on command line without specifying it in YAML?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Our team have been trying to develop some GUI for the ansible execution and I wanted to know if there is some way to pause the execution of the playbook midway with just command line argument.
I am familiar with the Pause option but that needs to be added in the YAML, we don't want that.
I am also familiar with the --step argument passed on the CLI, that's close to what we want but not specifically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the playbook is running you can press ctrl + s to freeze the console and then ctrl + q to resume it.

Comment: I wanted to ask if this just freezes the terminal output or the background processes too ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have found the only two options that would stop a playbook mid-play (pause and --step). As you're probably aware, Ansible is designed to run roles/playbooks start to finish without user intervention. Anything that allows you to stop mid-execution is really just for debugging.

What are you trying to accomplish by building a custom GUI? Have you looked into [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx)?

Comment: Yes, I've looked into both Ansible tower and AWX, both of them works good and solves most of our issues but not the whole problem.
There is a need for a custom in-house GUI that we can tweak and modify as we need it to function.